# php regex / preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match the numbers inside ('')

```
$linkvar ="<a onclick="javascript:open('597967');" class="links">more</a>"


preg_match("^[0-9]$",$linkvar,$result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex will only match if the string is exactly one digit. To match **only** the digits inside the quotes, use:

```
preg_match("/'(\d+)'/", $linkvar, $result);
var_dump($result[1]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regex only matches if the **entire** string is made up of one number because of the `^` and `$` modifiers. Your current regex translates in human language to:

1. `^` means "this is the start of the string"
2. `[0-9]` means "match a single numeric character"
3. `$` means "this is the end of the string"

Change it to:

```
preg_match("[0-9]+",$linkvar,$result);
```

Or alternatively, the shorthand syntax for matching numbers:

```
preg_match("\d+",$linkvar,$result);
```

The `+` modifier means that "one or more" numbers must be found in order for it to be a match.

Additionally, if you want to actually capture the numbers inside the string you'll need to add parentheses to inform `preg_match` that you actually want to "save" the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The ^ and $ match the start and end of the string, which means you are currently searching for a string containing ONLY a single digit. Remove them and add a plus quantifier, leaving just "[0-9]+", and it will find the first group of digits in the string.

```
preg_match("[0-9]+",$linkvar,$result);
```